# How to refresh or reload data

Tags: php, refresh, reloaddata

I would like to refresh any 60 sec only the values given back from the following code inside a widget, without reload the entire page:

```
    <?php
    // display Who's Online
    if (class_exists("VisitorMaps")) {
        $visitor_maps = new VisitorMaps();
    }
    if (isset($visitor_maps)) {
       $visitor_maps->visitor_maps_manual_sidebar();
    }
    ?>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you plan on using ajax ?

Answer (score 0):

Let me know more about your problem and then i might improve my answer
but you can use this js to get a response from server in json format and update only certain elements of html page
    /* refresh DOM for every key named 'selectors' in data dictionary
    */

```
/* both data and data['selectors'] need to be json objects
*/

var getJSON, refreshPage,
  __slice = [].slice;

refreshPage = function() {
  var callback, callbacks, content, data, dom, selector, selectors, _i, _len, _results;

  data = arguments[0], callbacks = 2 <= arguments.length ? __slice.call(arguments, 1) : [];
  selectors = data['selectors'];
  for (selector in selectors) {
    content = selectors[selector];
    if (!(content === '' || content === void 0)) {
      dom = $.toDom(selector);
      setText(dom, content, true);
    }
  }
  _results = [];
  for (_i = 0, _len = callbacks.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    callback = callbacks[_i];
    if (isFunction(callback)) {
      _results.push(callback(data));
    } else {
      _results.push(callback);
    }
  }
  return _results;
};

/* jquery getJSON function simplified
*/


/* calls the callback function with retrieved data automatically
*/


getJSON = function() {
  var args, callback, data, url;

  url = arguments[0], data = arguments[1], callback = arguments[2], args = 4 <= arguments.length ? __slice.call(arguments, 3) : [];
  return $.getJSON(url, data, function(data, status) {
    if (isFunction(callback)) {
      return callback.apply(null, [data].concat(__slice.call(args)));
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Wich information you need more?. All is there!. Very sample question but very complicate your answer.Sorry, but that doesn't help me!.

Comment: i know its complicated and u didnt answer me before when i asked if u want to use ajax or not ? and if you know cofeescript ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your question!.
I want use that code inside a widget of my Theme Wordpress. So I cannot decide if is better ajax or not, maybe. I try just before some ajax code, but it doesn't work, because I don't know wich file I must load and why. In any case I dont Know coffeescript.

Comment: I try this ajax, but nothing.

    <div id="responsecontainer"><?php contavisitatori(); ?></div>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#responsecontainer").load("<?php contavisitatori(); ?>");
    var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
    $("#responsecontainer").load('<?php contavisitatori(); ?>');
    }, 10000);
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    });
    </script>

Comment: contavisitatori() is a function in functions.php

Comment: do you know the id of that widget ? and when you create that widget from php, is the output in html form ?

Comment: The name of plugin is Visitor Maps for wordpress.

Comment: i dont know that plugin and your solution could be as simple as calling a function "getJSON(url, refreshPage)" every 60 seconds, only if you can trace which url is generating the output you want